# How to install GNOME Shell themes using GNOME tweak tool

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

Lately I've trying installing themes on ubuntu 12.04 through GNOME tweak tool but unfortunately I couldn't at last. I just wanted to know whether there is really possible to install themes on ubuntu as few websites claim to be?